# Spring Boot static resource access issue - Not able to access index.html under resources/static folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-rest

I am facing Spring Boot static resource access issue. Not able to access index.html under resources/static folder. I am not getting response with status code 401. Just getting a blank page whether I include index.html in my url path or not (for eg: http://localhost/erp/index.html) The request just passes through the authentication filter and rejected for absence of bearer token.

As I understand, spring supposed to automatically serve static resources. Can anyone tell me whether my Security configuration is preventing this automatic static resource serving? If so, how can I rectify it?

See below my Security Configuration.

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig 
{
    private final UserService loginUserService;
    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private ErpConstants erpConstants;
    
    public SecurityConfig(UserService loginUserService, JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, ErpConstants erpConstants)
    {
        this.loginUserService = loginUserService;
        this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;   
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.erpConstants = erpConstants;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(loginUserService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        http = http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http = http.csrf().disable();
        http = http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and();
        http = http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, ex) -> {response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, ex.getMessage());}).and();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize    
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/log-in").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated());
        
        // jwtRequestFilter is added before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to access user identity 
        // for performing authentication/authorization
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
               
        //http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        
        //To prevent browsers from just visiting the website using HTTP and then redirecting to HTTPS,
        // for prevent users being vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks
       // http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity();
        
        http.logout().disable();
        http.formLogin().disable();
        http.httpBasic().disable();
        http.anonymous().disable();     
        return http.build();
     }
    
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(erpConstants.getAllowedCorsOrigins());
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("content-type", "Authorization", "isRefreshToken"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: *The request just passes through the authentication filter and rejected for absence of bearer token.* You are permitting `index.html` with `.requestMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()`, so your request reaches your custom filter. If you don't want it, you have to restrict that URL.